# Pass Callback function to module.exports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom-events, serverside-javascript

I've written an USB Detection code with module exports , and I'd like to send 
also a callback function on the event fires.

Here :

```
module.exports = class USBDetection {
  constructor() {
    this.usb = require('usb');
    this.usbDetect = require('usb-detection');
  }

  startMonitoringDevices() {
    this.usbDetect.startMonitoring();
    // Detect add/insert
    this.usbDetect.on('add', function(device) {
      callback('add', device);
    });
    this.usbDetect.on('add:vid', function(device) {
      callback('add', device);
    });
    this.usbDetect.on('add:vid:pid', function(device) {
      callback('add', device);
    });

  }
};
```

How can I pass `callback` to the module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module.exports = callback => {
    const usb       = require('usb');
    const usbDetect = require('usb-detection');

    return {
        usb,
        usbDetect,
        startMonitoringDevices: () => {
            // Detect add/insert
            usbDetect.on('add', function(device) {
                callback('add', device);
            });
            ...
            usbDetect.startMonitoring();
        },
    };
};
```

Comment: Where is the name of the module ? `startMonitoringDevices` ?

Comment: ah, sorry about that - i just fixed it so the returned object exposes that function. you can name the module anything you like, e.g. `const foo = callback => {...}; module.exports = foo;`

Comment: you could also pass `callback` into that function, rather than the "constructor"

Answer (score 1):

So in your module :

```
  startMonitoringDevices(options = {}) {
    this.usbDetect.startMonitoring();
    // Detect add/insert
    this.usbDetect.on('add', function(device) {
      if (options.add !== undefined) {
          options.add('add', device);
      }
    });
    this.usbDetect.on('add:vid', function(device) {
      if (options.add !== undefined) {
          options.add('add', device);
      }
    });
    this.usbDetect.on('add:vid:pid', function(device) {
      if (options.add !== undefined) {
          options.add('add', device);
      }
    });
  }
```

In your caller

```
const usbDetect = new USBDetection();

usbDetect.startMonitoringDevices({
     add: function(eventType, device){
          console.log('it does its job');
     }
});
```